# Match column header and get rows below with for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to get all column data from `tabData` (`B1:I`) where the header (`B1:1`) is `> version` (`A3`).

So in the image below, it would be all of the data highlighted in green (`B2:E`)

Finally, I want to have only unique values.

I've tried several various functions without much success.  About the best I have done is narrow my `tabData` down to matches `> version`.  I've tried flattening the data before going into the for loop.  I've tried making the `tabData` unique first.  But then, I can't associate the data with the headers (at least, I'm not sure how). I'm probably over-complicating something that should be easy, but I'm not seeing it. I'm certain I'm on the right track, just doing things out of order or something.

Here's a link to [my script](https://script.google.com/d/1fyyeccIucS0FQ3gVL558bK1LdzUhphWtba0Msw0zjOmaXL3_f7U4U8B7/edit?mid=ACjPJvGWzlxj27B_odGE4VbuBAooP29S8WHDwfbWvvOzTq_wdgvvdFYSO510iFdWqpb3kDH_Wkd4jDV0rij3IAXAaH3CKYNoSdmnUoFlAbXBvKF5Bh7nSJCezS34Tdq3GFpt-vxw4kxybos&uiv=2) (`function getTabArray` in update.gs), if you'd like to see what I've done so far in action.

[image]

```js
function getTabArray() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var version = ss.getRangeByName("version").getValue().toString();
  var updateTabsName = "updateTabs";
  var updateTabsSheet = ss.getSheetByName(updateTabsName);
  var tabDataRows = updateTabsSheet.getLastRow();
  var tabDataCols = updateTabsSheet.getLastColumn() - 1; // -1 because we're starting in Col B
  var tabDataRange = updateTabsSheet.getRange(1, 2, tabDataRows, tabDataCols);
  var tabData = tabDataRange.getValues();
  var tabDataLen = tabData.length;
  Logger.log("// END VARIABLES //");

  // var tabDataFlat = [].concat(...tabData); // Flatten array
  // console.log(tabDataFlat);

  // tabDataFlat = tabDataFlat.filter(item => item); // Remove empties

  for (var i = 0; i < tabData.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tabDataCols; j++) {
      if (tabData[i] != "" && tabData[0][i] > version) {
        // Logger.log("tabData[0][i] = " + tabData[0][i]);
        Logger.log("tabData[j] = " + tabData[j]);
        // Logger.log("tabData[i][j] = " + tabData[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the CSV version of the data.  I'm sure there is a way to format it differently in the logger, but I wasn't able to find it.

```
[ [ '2.20200514.2', '2.20200514.0', '2.20200513.2', '2.20200513.1' ],
  [ 'Sheet6', 'Sheet7', 'Sheet6', 'Sheet7' ],
  [ 'settings', '', 'Sheet8', 'settings' ],
  [ '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '' ] ]
```

Comment: Can you supply csv data? Note: I will not follow links to spreadsheets and depending upon links to spreadsheets for your questions is a poor practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the header versions are in descending order and the version, A3 is present in range 1:1,

- get [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexof) A3 in row1
- trim length of each row to that index using [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

#### Snippet:

```
const tabData = tabDataRange.getValues();
const indexOfVersion = tabData[0].indexOf(version);
tabData.forEach(row => row.length = indexOfVersion);
console.info(tabData)
```

```js
const tabData = [ [ '2.20200514.2', '2.20200514.0', '2.20200513.2', '2.20200513.1' ],
  [ 'Sheet6', 'Sheet7', 'Sheet6', 'Sheet7' ],
  [ 'settings', '', 'Sheet8', 'settings' ],
  [ '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '' ],
  [ '', '', '', '' ] ];
const version = '2.20200513.1';
const indexOfVersion = tabData[0].indexOf(version);
tabData.forEach(row => row.length = indexOfVersion);
console.info(tabData.filter(row => row.some(String)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!  It's probably the correct answer, but I still can't manage to manipulate the data how I'm wanting. So I've thrown in the towel and have used a formula within the sheet and just grabbing that range.  Thank you again!

Comment: @Trey If you are having trouble, edit your question to add a update showing  your updated code and where the proposed solution is confusing for you. If this is a new question/ new goal, ask a new question

Comment: I ended up needing a similar function in another area of my sheet and was able to make it work this time. I may have been staring at this one for too long...